# Way to fetch value of github secret

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions, secret-key

Is there any way to fetch github secret value and display in workflow or fetch through library or APi or even github portal once it is stored.
I just want to validate.

Comment: related: https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets

Answer (score 2):

Github Actions replaces secret values in the log, so if you want to view the secret you must change its value first. Like this step:

```
- name: DISPLAY SECRETS
  run: echo ${{secrets.mysecret}} | sed 's/./& /g'
```

This will insert a space between each character of the secret, allowing you to see its value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to actually display the github secret value but there are ways to validate eg you can use if: {{secret_name}} == 'release' , then do this else do that.
Reference for writing if condition in github workflow: https://github.blog/changelog/2019-10-01-github-actions-new-workflow-syntax-features/