# Use Github action secrets on local machine - is it possible?

Tags: github, curl, github-actions

I know I can use curl to list the secrets of a repo via curl like so:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \                              
-H "Authorization: token [personal access token]" \
https://api.github.com/repos/[user]/[repo]/actions/secrets
```

This returns something like this:

```
{
  "total_count": 1,
  "secrets": [
    {
      "name": "A_TEST_SECRET",
      "created_at": "2022-04-14T13:12:22Z",
      "updated_at": "2022-04-14T13:12:22Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

But is it somehow possible to also retrieve the secret's value?

My use case is this:
I have a step in a Github Actions workflow that uses a secret and needs to be executed before I can run my `build` step, which just contains a script to run.

Now sometimes I want to also run my buildscript on my local machine, but to do that I also need to run the step before it, which needs the secret. Is there any way I can retrieve the secret's value  to a local machine from Github to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Way to fetch value of github secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62386905/way-to-fetch-value-of-github-secret)

Comment: It does not :-) That question is about checking the secret within a work flow. I would rather like to be able to access my repo's secrets from ly local machine. It looks like though, this is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by Github Partner [brightran](https://github.community/u/brightran) on this [Github Community Thread](https://github.community/t/how-to-see-my-git-secrets/123668):

> We have no safe way to fetch the values of secrets, and actually it is not recommended to try fetching and sharing the secrets.

---

He also shared in [that post](https://github.community/t/how-to-see-my-git-secrets/123668/2) two ways to use the repository secrets in the source code files of your project when you build the project in the workflow runs, maybe you can try them with your buildscript in a Github Actions workflow that could be triggered manually (using a [workflow_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) event, for example).

Comment: Thank you! Although this again talks about printing to the log in a workflow and not about fetching them remotely, just like you are able to fetch everything else from your repo using github's API, I am by now pretty certain, what I want is not possible. 
It is true that this might be considered "not safe" in some way, although for my use case I would tend to disagree. Anyway, it seems the system is designed to disallow it.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially this is a security risk so github only lets users to access secrets only via githhub actions.

But there's a way which is more of a workaround than a best practice.

We can store secret inside github and fetch that using a PAT with a repo scope.

Then we can use that PAT value inside the shell and call github API.

But there we need to securely store the PAT since we call its value directly in the shell script.

```
    TOKEN="YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN"
    REPO_USER="your_github_username"
    REPO_NAME="your_repo_name"
    SECRET_NAME="YOUR_SECRET_NAME"
    
    #Calling github API
    
    curl -H "Authorization: token $TOKEN" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
https://api.github.com/repos/$REPO_USER/$REPO_NAME/actions/secrets/$SECRET_NAME | jq .value
```

Hope above answer helps.