# Passing Github Action Workflow Secret to Local Python Environment

Tags: python, github, workflow, github-actions

I've seen a few similar questions here but I don't think this specific one has been answered yet. I am on a machine learning team and we do a LOT of discovery/exploratory analysis in a local environment.

I am trying to pass secrets stored in my github enterprise account to my local environment the same way that Azure Keyvault does.

Here is my workflow file:

```
name: qubole_access
on: [pull_request, push] 

env:
    ## Sets environment variable
  QUBOLE_API_TOKEN: ${{secrets.QUBOLE_API_TOKEN}}    

jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: self-hosted 
    steps:
      - name: step 1
        run: echo "The API key is:${{env.QUBOLE_API_TOKEN}}"
```

I can tell it's working because the job runs successfully in the workflow

[image: image of successful job in workflow]

The workflow file is referencing an API token to access our Qubole database. This token is stored as a secret in the 'secrets' area of my repo

[image: Secret Storage]

What I want to do now is reference that environment variable in a LOCAL python environment. It's important that it be in a local environment because it's less expensive and I don't want to risk anyone on my team accidentally forgetting and pushing secrets in their code, even if it's in a local git ignore file.

I have fetched/pulled/pushed/restarted etc etc and I can't get the variable into my environment.

[image: localenvironment]

When I check the environment variables by running env in the terminal, no environment variables show up there either.
Is there a way to treat github secrets like secrets in azure keyvault? Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Your question remembers me this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71872569/use-github-action-secrets-on-local-machine-is-it-possible/71913340#71913340 and the answer was that it's not possible to extract Github Actions secrets from Github repository, and it's not encouraged either.

Comment: The secrets in the actions tab get set inside the runner process at runtime if referenced in the workflow.  Its not clear why you think it would be set in your local dev environment.  unless I'm misunderstanding.  that would be on you to set locally.  is your goal for other devs to not have to set that secret?